# How to get accurate distance from WiFi in code?

Tags: linux, signal-processing, formula, measurement, rssi

I am working on a project in which I must determine distance from WiFi. I am using WiFi RSSI and the formula:

```
float exp = (27.55 - (20 * log10(frequency)) + abs(RSSI)) / 20.0;
return pow(10.0, exp);
```

But this not gives accurate value and depends on environment. If there is many walls between WiFi router and receiver this formula gives wrong value.

I have searched a lot in web. All the results are using RSSI and Tx-Power.
Tx-Power is RSSI at a distance of 1 meter to the WiFi router. Tx-Power is not a constant and varies from router to router and this means that my code will not work for all routers in the world.

My question is that how can I get distance from WiFi router accurate using this or another method?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using decibels, which depends on how good your WiFi detection will be. You can't use this formula if you are trying to get the distance, because it depends on the environment in which your router is.

Comment: Yes I know.I am asking for how can I calculate current distance?

Comment: do you know any other method?

Comment: can you give me a method that I can count signal trip time or wifi responce time?